# Help : Someone please help me merge my accounts

Tags: support, status-completed, merge-accounts

Hello

Can someone help in merging my accounts on programmers stack exchange ?

please merge [this account](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/9779/user9009) into the [new one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/17335/user9009)

I'm not able to access my old account because of lost openid credentials

Thanks

Comment: You posted this with the account id 9779 which is the one you want merging into 17335. Which one do you want to keep?

Comment: i want keep the one ending in 17335

Comment: Now that's odd the id of the account has now changed to 17335.

Comment: i have other accounts StackOverflow, AskUbuntu etc linked to 17335

Comment: There's something odd with these accounts. The associations seem mixed up and the owner of this post is reported as 17335 here but 9779 on the questions list. I've asked for a developer to look into it.

Comment: Yeah sure, To be frank i was actually testing this feature on StackOverflow website. Am glad i was able to find a bug :). Thanks